# Python match a number within a string

Tags: python

I need to check if a string matches `ORA-16252: unable to extend segment by <any value> in tablespace`. Here `<any value>` can be any number. How do I match the string in python? Is there a regular expression for that?

Comment: What kind of number?  Integer, float?  Hex? Scientific notation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
regex = re.compile(r'ORA-16252: unable to extend segment by \d+ in tablespace')
if regex.match(s):
    ...
```

Comment: what if i want to match both integer and floating numbers??

Comment: why is that 'r' put in front of ORA-16252?

Comment: @Sandeep Krishnan: The r means that it is a raw string literal. In a raw string literal backslash always means backslash. For instance '\n' is a return character but r'\n' is backslash followed by the letter 'n'. Since backslash is common in regular expressions, it is standard practice to always use raw string literals when writing regular expressions. (In the answer to your question the r is in fact not needed.)

Comment: @Sandeep Krishnan: For a Python regular expression that matches floating point numbers, see http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/12929308

Answer (score 0):

`\\d+` is used to match one or more number of digits is continuity. So, you can just add it in place of your `<any value>` to match any number.

Rest of the strings, since it does not vary as you are saying, keep it as it is.

```
m = re.search(r'ORA-16252: unable to extend segment by \d+ in tablespace', 
               yourString)

if m is not None:
    # set your value
```