# Python regular expression that matches floating point numbers

Tags: python, regex, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect a floating point number using a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293780/how-to-detect-a-floating-point-number-using-a-regular-expression)

How do I write a Python regular expression that matches string representations of floating point numbers?

The expression should match any string that is accepted by the `float` constructor as in `float('3.5')`. Thus the expression should match `'0.'` and `'.0'` but not `'.'`

There is no need to match string representations of infinity and NaN.

Comment: Tongue in cheek answer: `try: float(foo) except ValueError: ...`

Comment: @Amber: Yes, but that can not be used as a building block to build more complex regular expressions.

Comment: Hence the tongue in cheek aspect.

Comment: Why the `locale` tag? Do you also want to match floating point numbers with thousands separators (`1,234.56`), alternative decimal separators (`1'234,56`), non-ASCII digits, other numbering systems like the South Asian one (`1,00,000.00`) etc.?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: Fixed. I forgot to set the tags. Stackoverflow must have selected them automatically. (I have no intent to support Nepalese 100000 separators.)

Comment: You mention: "...can not be used as a building block..." - would you care  to share the bigger picture of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Jon Clements: Nothing interesting really. For instance, a regular expression for parsing strings such as 'x=2.3 y=-5.8'.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to check out [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com) before you go too far down the regex road

Comment: Take a look at the regex that Python's decimal module uses:  http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/943d3e289ab4/Lib/decimal.py#l6098  You'll probably want to adjust the bits for special values (NaNs, infinities).

Comment: @Mark Dickinson: That is a nice regex. If the question is reopened, please submit an answer based on that. You will get my upvote.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
r'[+-]?(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)([eE][+-]?\d+)?'
```

Comment: What about 05.5, which is an invalid floating point number, can be also matched by this regex? And 5.5e+1.2. This is also valid, but cannot be matched by the regex.

Comment: @Jingjie Zhan: Both Python and C++ accept 05.5 as a valid floating point literal. Neither Python nor C++ accepts 5.5e+1.2.

Comment: @Jingjie Zhan: But you are right that the regex is not 100% correct. `05.0`, `05.` and `05e0` are valid floating point literals, while `05` is not (it is an octal integer literal). The regular expression however accepts all four strings.

Comment: this doesnt work for 43543ff5.4 so put any alphabets in the number and it will pass

Comment: @Adobri You are right. I think adding anchors (`^` and `$`) like so `r'^[+-]?(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)([eE][+-]?\d+)?$'` will at least reject 43543ff5.4 as it should