# Python: list comprehension with multiple conditions

Tags: python

I have:

```
s=  'Lot Size: 1.52 acres'
```

I want to return a float number only (1.52)

I tried:

```
>>> o =[s for s in str.split('') if s.isdigit() if s=='.']
>>>

>>>o
>>>[]
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: why do you need a list in the end?

Comment: What do you expect `str.split('')` to do? When I try to run what you have, I get `ValueError: empty separator`. Is this Python 2?

Comment: Use regex? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929308/python-regular-expression-that-matches-floating-point-numbers/12929311

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following, with a singular condition and in keeping with your original format (*using python 3.6.8*) :)

**Multiple condition syntax:**

```
[ x for x in x.do() if 'x' in x OR/AND if x == 1]
```

**Example:**

```
s = 'Lot Size: 1.52 acres'

o = [s for s in s.split(' ') if '.' in s]

print(o[0])
```

**Output:**

```
1.52
```

Comment: Note that this won't work for "numbers" that don't have exactly 1 decimal point.

Comment: Well said, will need adjusting for use against a wider range of inputs :) @ScottHunter

Comment: This only works because you aren't calling `s.isdigit` -- notice the lack of parenthesis.  Change it to `s.isdigit()` and it fails because `'1.52'.isdigit()` is `False`.

Comment: Resorting to a singular condition gives a bad answer with even slightly different input: `s = 'Lot Sz.: 1.52 acres'`

Answer (score 5):

This will assign to `o` a list of the "words" in `msg` that can be interpreted as floats:

```
def isFloat(n):
    try:
        return float(n)
    except:
        return None

o = list(filter(isFloat,msg.split()))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is by using regular expressions:

```
import re

s='Lot Size: 1.52 acres'
result = float(re.findall("[0-9]+\.[0-9]+", s)[0])
print(result)
```

This will give you:

```
1.52
```

Or, in case you want a list of floats as a result:

```
result = list(map(float,(re.findall("[0-9]+\.[0-9]+", s))))
```

Comment: This assumes that there is a decimal point with at least one digit on either side.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
o = float(s.split(':')[1].split('acres')[0].strip())
```

Comment: Why would you being on iOS prevent me from copying/pasting?

Comment: You're assuming quite a bit about the structure of this string.  If we're going to assume let's just assume it's the third item `o = float(s.split()[2])`.